# Comparing multiple time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-comparisons

If I have many time series that I'd like to compare to see if there are relationships between the variables, (I have several dependent variables and many more independent variables) how might I go about doing this (I'm working in R, just fyi)? I haven't really found too many examples seeking to compare and explore the relationships between many variables. In particular, I'd like to see if the variation in my independent time series drives variation in the dependent time series, and I'm so new to statistics (and R) that I'm really not sure how to approach this problem. Here is some sample data (I know there are 2 missing values, and I may choose to treat Y2 as an independent variable since I think Y2 and Y1 may be correlated.  The column labeled "covariate" is years since last flood, because I think this might be important too):

```
year Y1 Y2  X1  X2  X3      X4  X5  covariate
1    40  92 0   0   20.6    91  503 3
2    54  65 0   0   21.7    33  175 4
3    59  75 1   1   22.2    34  94  5
4    68  53 8   9   22.2    24  86  6
5           5   20  20.6    5   185 7
6    76  65 8   13  22.2    32  119 8
7    76  55 16  18  23.3    0   153 9
8    82  58 18  2   24.4    19  0   1
9    60  57 28  24  23.33   0   223 2
10   58  46 18  3   22.78   0   184 3
11   49  48 2   1   23.33   0   110 4
12   28  76 0   3   22.78   0   213 5
13   56  61 0   1   22.78   12  123 6
14   105 53 56  24  23.33   0   122 7
15   99  43 28  13  24.44   0   154 8
16   119 47 46  35  23.33   0   182 9
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated as I'm not really sure how to proceed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here goes ... These are the steps that are required to form your analysis. Simply reproduce them in R or whatever tools you have available. The reason the following exercise is daunting is because the statistical problem you are asking is "daunting" and one needs to "up-armor" their solutions skills/procedures.

1. pre-whiten each of your 7 candidate regressors in order to identify an initial Tranfer Function model of the form

   ```
     MODEL COMPONENT       LAG    COEFF     STANDARD      P       T
   ```

   ## (BOP)              ERROR      VALUE   VALUE

   1CONSTANT                         -258.       330.      0.4568    -0.78

   INPUT SERIES X1  Y2

   2Omega (input) -Factor #  1    0  0.635      0.583      0.3079     1.09

   INPUT SERIES X2  X1

   3Omega (input) -Factor #  2    1  0.544      0.563      0.3623     0.97

   INPUT SERIES X3  X2

   4Omega (input) -Factor #  3    0   1.60      0.485      0.0110     3.29

   INPUT SERIES X4  X3

   5Omega (input) -Factor #  4    0   11.7       14.8      0.4493     0.80

   INPUT SERIES X5  X4

   6Omega (input) -Factor #  5    0  0.491      0.699      0.5020     0.70

   INPUT SERIES X6  X5

   7Omega (input) -Factor #  6    0 -0.151      0.164      0.3852    -0.92

   INPUT SERIES X7  X6

   8Omega (input) -Factor #  7    0   2.40       1.57      0.1639     1.53

Then do Interventon Detection to extract any anomalies in the data finding three

```
         :  NEWLY IDENTIFIED VARIABLE   X8   I~P00010       10    PULSE     
         :  NEWLY IDENTIFIED VARIABLE   X9   I~P00014       14    PULSE     
         :  NEWLY IDENTIFIED VARIABLE   X10  I~P00002        2    PULSE
```

This leads to an augmented model :

```
      MODEL COMPONENT       LAG    COEFF     STANDARD      P       T
```

#                            (BOP)              ERROR      VALUE   VALUE

```
1CONSTANT                         -33.9       191.      0.8662    -0.18
```

INPUT SERIES X1  Y2

```
2Omega (input) -Factor #  1    0   1.08      0.324      0.0207     3.34
```

INPUT SERIES X2  X1

```
3Omega (input) -Factor #  2    1  0.867      0.325      0.0446     2.67
```

INPUT SERIES X3  X2

```
4Omega (input) -Factor #  3    0   2.06      0.248      0.0004     8.29
```

INPUT SERIES X4  X3

```
5Omega (input) -Factor #  4    0   1.68       8.47      0.8503     0.20
```

INPUT SERIES X5  X4

```
6Omega (input) -Factor #  5    0 -0.239      0.455      0.6218    -0.53
```

INPUT SERIES X6  X5

```
7Omega (input) -Factor #  6    0 -0.363      0.102      0.0161    -3.56
```

INPUT SERIES X7  X6

```
8Omega (input) -Factor #  7    0   3.21      0.712      0.0064     4.50
```

INPUT SERIES X8  I~P00010       10    PULSE

```
9Omega (input) -Factor #  8    0   30.4       6.52      0.0055     4.66
```

INPUT SERIES X9  I~P00014       14    PULSE

10Omega (input) -Factor #  9    0   14.7       6.42      0.0709     2.29

INPUT SERIES X 10 I~P00002        2    PULSE

11Omega (input) -Factor # 10    0   39.6       8.22      0.0048     4.81

which is over-specified thus we must step-down and obtain

```
      MODEL COMPONENT       LAG    COEFF     STANDARD      P       T
```

#                            (BOP)              ERROR      VALUE   VALUE

```
1CONSTANT                         -2.32       7.25      0.7584    -0.32
```

INPUT SERIES X1  Y2

```
2Omega (input) -Factor #  1    0   1.10      0.872E-01  0.0000    12.58
```

INPUT SERIES X2  X1

```
3Omega (input) -Factor #  2    1   1.04      0.103      0.0000    10.10
```

INPUT SERIES X3  X2

```
4Omega (input) -Factor #  3    0   2.04      0.199      0.0000    10.22
```

INPUT SERIES X4  X5

```
5Omega (input) -Factor #  4    0 -0.335      0.301E-01  0.0000   -11.13
```

INPUT SERIES X5  X6

```
6Omega (input) -Factor #  5    0   2.84      0.663      0.0037     4.28
```

INPUT SERIES X6  I~P00010       10    PULSE

```
7Omega (input) -Factor #  6    0   27.8       6.48      0.0036     4.29
```

INPUT SERIES X7  I~P00014       14    PULSE

```
8Omega (input) -Factor #  7    0   21.3       6.17      0.0107     3.45
```

INPUT SERIES X8  I~P00002        2    PULSE

```
9Omega (input) -Factor #  8    0   32.3       5.99      0.0010     5.39
```

which now will suggest additional structure in the X's via cross-correlative tests between the current model residuals and the residuals from the pre-whitened X's .... that had previously remained unidentified.

```
      MODEL COMPONENT       LAG    COEFF     STANDARD      P       T
```

#                            (BOP)              ERROR      VALUE   VALUE

```
1CONSTANT                         -25.8       6.12      0.0083    -4.22
```

INPUT SERIES X1  Y2

```
2Omega (input) -Factor #  1    0   1.11      0.598E-01  0.0000    18.50
3                              1 -0.211      0.516E-01  0.0095    -4.09
```

INPUT SERIES X2  X1

```
4Omega (input) -Factor #  2    1   1.05      0.692E-01  0.0000    15.23
```

INPUT SERIES X3  X2

```
5Omega (input) -Factor #  3    0   2.28      0.143      0.0000    15.99
```

INPUT SERIES X4  X5

```
6Omega (input) -Factor #  4    0 -0.311      0.193E-01  0.0000   -16.17
7                              1 -0.693E-01  0.103E-01  0.0011    -6.72
```

INPUT SERIES X5  X6

```
8Omega (input) -Factor #  5    0   2.19      0.466      0.0054     4.70
```

INPUT SERIES X6  I~P00010       10    PULSE

```
9Omega (input) -Factor #  6    0   19.8       4.31      0.0059     4.59
```

INPUT SERIES X7  I~P00014       14    PULSE

10Omega (input) -Factor #  7    0   18.6       4.21      0.0068     4.43

culminating in the final model

MODEL STATISTICS AND EQUATION FOR THE CURRENT EQUATION (DETAILS FOLLOW).

Estimation/Diagnostic Checking for Variable Y    Y1
                                            X1   Y2
                                            X2   X1
                                            X3   X2
                                            X4   X5
                                            X5   X6
             :  NEWLY IDENTIFIED VARIABLE   X6   I~P00010       10    PULSE
             :  NEWLY IDENTIFIED VARIABLE   X7   I~P00014       14    PULSE

Number of Residuals (R)        =n                         15
 Number of Degrees of Freedom   =n-m                        7
 Residual Mean                  =Sum R / n              -0.204655E-04
 Sum of Squares                 =Sum R**2                 171.679
 Variance                       =SOS/(n)                  10.7299
 Adjusted Variance              =SOS/(n-m)                12.2628
 Standard Deviation RMSE        =SQRT(Adj Var)            3.50183
 Standard Error of the Mean     =Standard Dev/ (n-m)     0.935902
 Mean / its Standard Error      =Mean/SEM               -0.218671E-04
 Mean Absolute Deviation        =Sum(ABS(R))/n            2.50518
 AIC Value ( Uses var )         =nln  +2m                 37.5956
 SBC Value ( Uses var )         =nln  +m*lnn              38.3036
 BIC Value ( Uses var )         =see Wei p153             64.1437
 R Square                       =                        0.986111
 Durbin-Watson Statistic        =[-A(T-1)]**2/A**2        2.85557

```
 D-W STATISTIC IS INCONCLUSIVE.
```

THE DURBIN-WATSON STATISTIC IS VALID ONLY FOR MODELS THAT HAVE A WHITE NOISE
 ERROR TERM AND NO LAGS OF THE Y SERIES. OTHERWISE IT IS INVALID.
 IN THIS CASE THE TEST IS VALID.

AUTOMATICALLY REVISING MODEL

```
      MODEL COMPONENT       LAG    COEFF     STANDARD      P       T
```

#                            (BOP)              ERROR      VALUE   VALUE

```
1CONSTANT                         -25.8       6.12      0.0029    -4.22
```

INPUT SERIES X1  Y2

```
2Omega (input) -Factor #  1    0   1.11      0.598E-01  0.0000    18.50
3                              1 -0.211      0.516E-01  0.0035    -4.09
```

INPUT SERIES X2  X1

```
4Omega (input) -Factor #  2    1   1.05      0.692E-01  0.0000    15.23
```

INPUT SERIES X3  X2

```
5Omega (input) -Factor #  3    0   2.28      0.143      0.0000    15.99
```

INPUT SERIES X4  X5

```
6Omega (input) -Factor #  4    0 -0.311      0.193E-01  0.0000   -16.17
7                              1 -0.693E-01  0.103E-01  0.0001    -6.72
```

INPUT SERIES X5  X6

```
8Omega (input) -Factor #  5    0   2.19      0.466      0.0016     4.70
```

INPUT SERIES X6  I~P00010       10    PULSE

```
9Omega (input) -Factor #  6    0   19.8       4.31      0.0018     4.59
```

INPUT SERIES X7  I~P00014       14    PULSE

10Omega (input) -Factor #  7    0   18.6       4.21      0.0022     4.43

Y(T) = -25.800
       +[X1(T)][(+ 1.1058+ 0.211B** 1)]
       +[X2(T)][(+ 1.0543B** 1)]
       +[X3(T)][(+ 2.2848)]
       +[X4(T)][(- 0.311+ 0.0693B** 1)]
       +[X5(T)][(+ 2.1900)]
       +[X6(T)][(+ 19.8039)]
       +[X7(T)][(+ 18.6231)]

Comment: Wow, thank you for your answer!  I'm a real novice at statistics, and I do not entirely understand what you've done here. I wish I knew how to reproduce this in R so that I could examine the steps in the process, and look up the various functions being used.

Comment: I removed your comment replying to Frank because (1) it is counterproductive, from the point of view of this site, to split discussions off to some other location and (2) it's a bad idea to post your email addresses in such a public, searchable spot.

Comment: @whuber ok I agree . I will edit my post and eliminate those two things.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help me out and to further my understanding!  It was quite productive for me!

Comment: -1 for: implying that this is the only solution ("required"), code input/output in some unspecified language, terrible formatting, poor explanation of what your model actually means.

Comment: @naught101 Thanks for your suggestions as to how I can improve. To identify relationships between time the simple cross-correlation is meaningless due to auto-correlation. This is why we filter to IDENTIFY the relationships. Additionally outliers/inliers/level shifts/local time time trends need to be identified via INTERVENTION DETECTION so we can get an unobstructed view ( robust analysis ) of the statistical signifcance of the suggested "regression structure" Hope this helps you and others !